# Changing View Height inside a custom ScrollView onScrollChanged

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-scrolling

I'm trying to make the following effect:

[image: example]

I have a custom ScrollView (in oder to get the onScrollChanged listener) and a custom View inside it. In the custom View I succeed to place the item as I want.

Here my customView:

```
public class CustomView extends FrameLayout {

private TextView nameView;
private TextView emailView;
private ImageView addressView;
private Tracks track ;
private double scrollProgress = 0.0;
private double topViewScaleFactor = 2.0;
private double collapsedViewHeight = 200.0;
private double expandedViewHeight = 700.0; 
private double scrollProgressPerView = expandedViewHeight;

View v;
View firstItem;
View secondView;


          int itemMinHeight = 200;
          int itemMaxHeight = 700;

public CustomView(MyScrollView paramEventListView, Context paramContext){

           super(paramContext);
}        



public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}


public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}


public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

    @Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int m = getMeasuredWidth();


         int itemWidth = (r-l)/getChildCount();
       //  int itemHeight = (b-t)/getChildCount();


         firstItem = getChildAt(0);
        //firstItem.layout(0, 0, r-l, itemMaxHeight);
         firstItem.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(m, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(itemMaxHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
         firstItem.layout(0, 0, r-l, itemMaxHeight);

         secondView = getChildAt(1);
         secondView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(m, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(itemMinHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
         secondView.layout(0, itemMaxHeight, r-l, itemMinHeight+itemMaxHeight);

         int FirstAndSEcondItemHeight = firstItem.getHeight() + secondView.getHeight();
         for(int i=2; i< this.getChildCount(); i++){
              v = getChildAt(i);
          //  v.layout(itemWidth*i, 0, (i+1)*itemWidth, b-t); 

             v.layout(0, FirstAndSEcondItemHeight + (itemMinHeight*(i-2)), r-l, FirstAndSEcondItemHeight + ((i-1)*itemMinHeight)); 
         }


}


    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);



    int heightMeasured = 0;
    /*for each child get height and
    heightMeasured += childHeight;*/
     for(int i=0; i< this.getChildCount(); i++){
         heightMeasured += getChildAt(i).getHeight();
     }

    //If I am in a scrollview i got heightmeasurespec == 0, so
    if(heightMeasureSpec == 0){
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightMeasured, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec), getDefaultSize(this.getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec));
}
```

Here my Custom ScrollView:

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView{



public MyScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    add(context);
} 

public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setScrollViewListener(ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener) {
    this.scrollViewListener = scrollViewListener;


}
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
    super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldx, oldy);

 // How can I acces to each child in the customView class, and change their height depending on the scrollChanged


}
```

But now I need to change the item height when I scroll the scrollview. I don't know what to put in the onScrollChanged...
If someone has an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Hey! I have to implement the same thing. Can you tell me what you ended up doing?

Comment: For information I have seen a library, but not tested yet: https://github.com/borjabravo10/FocusResize?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=905515fe31-Android_Weekly_213&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-905515fe31-337890417

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to force the view to redraw by calling `invalidate()`?

From comment: I think you need to move your code in the onMeasure method to replace the "TODO" stub, so that super.onMeasure() is called after your manipulations. And make sure you're passing the new width/height calculations to it.

Comment: Maybe :) Where do I need to put the invalidate()?
In the OnScrollChanged or in the overide methode onDraw()?

Comment: Invalidate will itself call onDraw, so you don't want it there. I was suggesting to do it in onScrollChanged. Of course this is assuming that the view would recalculate the height of each child when it redraws.

Comment: I'm doing this:

    View second = custoView.getChildAt(1);
    custoView.setChildHeight(second, (int)(MIN_ITEM_ROW +1.5*100));
    custoView.invalidate();

There is no change in the child height...
But as in the onLayout() of my customView I set the default item height when placing child, when calling invalidate(), do it will recreate the childs from the onlayout() and set again the item default height? or I missing something?

Comment: Actually I succeed to change the height of an item view; But the view group (containing all the item), I cannot change is height, it doesn't move even if one of his child has a heigh bigger that the biginning...
Do I need to do something on onSizeChanged(..)?

Comment: I think you need to move your code in the onMeasure method to replace the "TODO" stub, so that super.onMeasure() is called after your manipulations. And make sure you're passing the new width/height calculations to it.

Comment: @Chol How are you adding views to your Custom Layout? and how are you animating?

Comment: Actually I did something not really good, I mean there is not recycling. So it is working for small amount of item (arround 10). My custoView is a viewGroup, I just add item to it. For the animating: I know there is a total of 10 items x itemMaxHeight. Depending on the scrollY, I'm checking for all item position and make the item linear layout bigger on the current item displayed. It is hard to explain, but I know it is not the right way, I'm still looking for a better solution